# How to change / convert date time timezone format to date format only in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

In one of my table it has a column for date and it saves `VARCHAR` value because of the timezone format `2019-12-30 00:00:01 +0800`. Is there a way to change / convert it to `date` format only and create a query for range of date? I'm having difficulties in converting it to date only. I tried to change to date in php but I am wondering how to convert it in SQL because I need to query range of dates. 
Thank you in advance for the help.

I'm having an error `Incorrect datetime value: '2020-01-14 00:00:01 +0800' for function str_to_date`

What I tried is

```
(STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y/%m/%d") between DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY("2020-01-14"), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) AND LAST_DAY("2020-01-14") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s +%x%x%x%x")   FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s +%x%x%x%x")  between DATE_ADD(
         DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY("2020-01-14"), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) 
    AND LAST_DAY("2020-01-14") ;
```

See examole

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.19    |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`placed_date` varchar(30))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`placed_date`)
> VALUES
>     ("2019-12-30 00:00:01 +0800"),
>     ("2019-12-29 00:00:01 +0800"),
>     ("2019-12-28 00:00:01 +0800"),
>     ("2019-12-27 00:00:01 +0800"),
>         ("2020-01-02 00:00:01 +0800")
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s +%x%x%x%x")    FROM table1
> WHERE STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s +%x%x%x%x")  between DATE_ADD(
>          DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY("2020-01-14"), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) 
>     AND LAST_DAY("2020-01-14") ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s +%x%x%x%x") |
> | :------------------------------------------------------ |
> | 2020-01-02 00:00:01                                     |
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE  table1 SET placed_date =  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s +%x%x%x%x"), "%Y-%m-%d");
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY placed_date DATE;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | placed_date |
> | :---------- |
> | 2019-12-30  |
> | 2019-12-29  |
> | 2019-12-28  |
> | 2019-12-27  |
> | 2020-01-02  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f98cf563cfbc7497b2f7cd2cca0d009)*

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error, but there are two possibilities:

1. It could be because the seconds, and the timezone `+0800` cannot be understood as a component of date in mysql.

You could try to use only the date part of the original string to be converted to date, using `SUBSTRING`:

```
(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(placed_date,1,10), "%Y/%m/%d")
    between DATE_ADD(
         DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY("2020-01-14"), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) 
    AND LAST_DAY("2020-01-14") )
```

2. Since the date format you want is in `%Y-%m-%d`, try using this instead of `%Y/%m/%d`.

```
(STR_TO_DATE(placed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
    between DATE_ADD(
         DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY("2020-01-14"), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) 
    AND LAST_DAY("2020-01-14") )
```

I personally think 2) is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT  placed_date,SUBSTRING_INDEX(placed_date,' ',1) FROM test1
WHERE   SUBSTRING_INDEX(placed_date,' ',1) 
BETWEEN (LAST_DAY('2020-01-14') + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND LAST_DAY('2020-01-14');
```

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` only and you can use `INTERVAL` function directly with plus minus operator (+-) without `DATE_ADD`.

Fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3qXHtWT1amyCLvasW7SpfH/2